# Download a file from Android share intent

Tags: android, android-intent

My app has the option to share a generated GPX file (a hiking route) with other applications. I'm using the ACTION_SEND intent for this. It works well, and users can share the GPX files with other apps and with other people via email etc.

However, some apps do not seem to accept receiving this data via intents. Garmin Connect does not show up in the list of apps when I'm sharing a GPX file, using the content type "application/gpx+xml".

If I download the GPX file manually and then open it, then Garmin Connect is listed as an app that can open it.

Is there any way to add a "Download file" to the share chooser intent that pops up when sharing a file?

Here is the client code I'm using:

```
private final WeakReference<MainActivity> mainActivityWeakReference;

public FileExportTask(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    this.mainActivityWeakReference = new WeakReference<>(mainActivity);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();

    if (mainActivity == null) {
        // TODO: handle that mainActivity doesn't exist
        return;
    }

    try {
        Uri uri = getUriForSelectedRoute();
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            shareIntent.setType("application/gpx+xml");
            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, mainActivity.getString(R.string.share_route));

            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = mainActivity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(chooser, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                mainActivity.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }

            mainActivity.startActivity(chooser);
        });
    } catch (Exception ioe) {
        mainActivity.runOnUiThread(() -> Toast.makeText(mainActivity, R.string.failed_route_share, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());
    }
}

private Uri getUriForSelectedRoute() throws Exception {

    Route selectedRoute = RouteResponseProvider.getInstance().getSelectedRoute();
    return downloadRoute(selectedRoute.toGpxUrl());
}

private Uri downloadRoute(String url) throws IOException {

    String filename = "route_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".gpx";
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new UserAgentInterceptor())
            .build();

    Request httpRequest = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    try (Response response = client.newCall(httpRequest).execute()) {
        File downloadedFile = new File(getFilesDirectory(), filename);
        BufferedSink sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(downloadedFile));
        sink.writeAll(response.body().source());
        sink.close();
        return getContentUri(downloadedFile);
    }
}

private File getFilesDirectory() {
    MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();
    File dir = mainActivity.getFilesDir();
    if (dir != null && !dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    return dir;
}

private Uri getContentUri(File file) {
    MainActivity mainActivity = mainActivityWeakReference.get();
    return FileProvider.getUriForFile(mainActivity, "com.myapp.fileprovider", file);
}
```

And this is in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

Comment: "Garmin Connect does not show up in the list of apps when I'm sharing a GPX file" -- install [this app](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.oF2pks.applicationsinfo/) and examine Garmin Connect's manifest to see what MIME types it supports.

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, it seems to support the content type I'm sending (application/gpx+xml) but it's not showing up. The Garmin Connect intent filters are at https://gist.github.com/samcrawford/0248b715b46d5983a1502d9f7acc06fd, whilst an app that does work (GPX Viewer) has intent filters at https://gist.github.com/samcrawford/bd7551b8599d6f7c8bd9a79d8d178aab.

Comment: Frankly, both apps' manifests suck. They will both fail for lots of valid `Intent`s. Could you add a [mcve] showing how you are creating your `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, in particular how you are setting up the `Uri`? I might be able to show you how to adjust it to happen to hit both of these.

Comment: Code added, thanks!

Comment: If your extracted manifest bits are correct, Garmin Connect does not support `ACTION_SEND` at all. It only supports `ACTION_VIEW`. Since the default action of a file manager is `ACTION_VIEW`, that would explain your difference in results. You might need to add `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` to `shareIntent` to offer `ACTION_VIEW` as well as `ACTION_SEND` in a single `Intent`.

Comment: Great spot - thanks! Yes, switching to ACTION_SEND makes Garmin Connect appear. Sadly, from trying it and reading around, it doesn't look like EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS is viable on Android 10+. Unless you have any other ideas I'll probably have to implement both separately.

Comment: I cannot think of anything specific to `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` that changed recently, though I can't rule it out.